# Jquery: ajaxComplete wont get the response

Tags: jquery

Hi :) When using Firebug i can see it returns 0 or 1, so the php is ok. But seems like ajax server_reponse isnt getting it.. somehow. Anyone see the problem?

```
j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/inc/ajax_check_username.php",
    data: "username=" + username,
    success: function (server_response) {

        j("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function (event, request) {
            if (server_response == '0') {
                alert('ledig..');
                j("#availability_status").html('<p>Ok 0</p> <font color="Green"> Ledig! </font>');
            } else if (server_response == '1') {
                alert('IKKE ledig..');
                j("#availability_status").html('<p>Ok 1</p> <font color="red">Ikke Ledig... </font>');
            }

        });
    } // server resp
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried just this

```
j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/inc/ajax_check_username.php",
    data: "username=" + username,
    success: function (server_response) {   

            if (server_response == '0') {
                alert('ledig..');
                j("#availability_status").html('<p>Ok 0</p> <font color="Green"> Ledig! </font>');
            } else if (server_response == '1') {
                alert('IKKE ledig..');
                j("#availability_status").html('<p>Ok 1</p> <font color="red">Ikke Ledig... </font>');
            }    

    } // server resp
});
```

and what are the possible response from server? just '0' or '1'?

Comment: Thanx for the edit, couldnt get the code thingy to work :/.

Tried removing .ajaxComplete.. now but same thing, nothing :p Seems like it stops at the If, have an alert just before it and that fires.

Comment: based on my answer above, try `alert(server_response)` before `if (server_response == '0') {...` let see if we got something...

Comment: woh.. it reponded correct! 0 and 1 with hit. 

Ok.. removed the '' around 0 and 1 ,and now it works 100% :)) Guess its because its data, not text.. or?

Comment: Works fine with server_response == 0 NOT server_response == '0' :D

Thanks very much!! :)